# Trying to search for item in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

```
def dataFinder(username):
    readData = csv.reader(open("patient_data.csv", "r"))
    for row in readData:
        print(row[0])
        if row[0] == username:
            print("True")
            break
    else:
        print("False")

username = "username"
dataFinder(username)
```

So when I run this it prints row[0] as "username" however, it returns false when it compares row[0] to the variable username, they appear the same and this code has worked in other programs I have run so why isn't it working here?

Comment: Can you provide the csv file? or a part of it?

Comment: Does your csv really start with "username,"? Is there a weird BOM that the csv reader fails to parse?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Typically comparison issues like this are caused by formatting or spacing differences.

The easiest way to solve this problem for yourself will be using the lovely [difflib.ndiff](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) function.

For an example I just wrote:

```
import csv
import io

import difflib

CSV_FILE=u' \uefeffusername,password\r\n matt,hunter2'

data = csv.reader(io.StringIO(CSV_FILE))

username = "username"
for row in data:
  print ("'" + row[0] + "'")

  print("".join(difflib.ndiff(username, row[0])))
```

The output is:

```
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
' fusername'
+  + + f  u  s  e  r  n  a  m  e
' matt'
+  + m- u- s- e- r- n  a- m- e+ t+ t

```

Now it's obvious that the first line doesn't match because I have an extra space and an unprintable block character, the second line doesn't match at all. Add this check to your script and you can fix your data source.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, forgot csv.reader treats the first line as field names and so skips it out.